# Objective-C: constant string vs dynamic string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to combine strings with numbers to load dynamic a texture. I found out that the behavior is different if I use a NSString and assign a static string or I combine the string with a number.

```
// version 1
NSString* textureName;
textureName = @"texture_1";

// version 2
NSString* textureName;
textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"texture_%i ",index];
```

When I try to get an item from my dictionary with textureName as my key I get the item with the first version of my code but I dont get it with the second version.

The debugger shows in version 1 the type "_*NSCFConstantString" and in version 2 the type "*_NSCFString".

How can I get an item out of my dictionary with a dynamic string?

Comment: Can you include the code where you define `index` and where you try to retrieve the value?

Comment: Please show how you retrieve data from dictionary. Also, what is `index`, where, how is it declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your second string has a space at the end. `@"texture_1"` is not considered the same as `@"texture_1 "`.

Comment: Thank you, obviously I was blind... :-) I thought I am going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe as simple as overlooking a trailing whitespace

Look at the last character in version 2. There is space on the end. Remove it and it should work.

```
// version 2
NSString* textureName;
textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"texture_%i ",index];
```

Comment: Thank you, obviously I was blind... :-)